# Gradle JacocoTestReports task is skipped on bamboo build server but builds fine on local machine

Tags: android, gradle, jacoco

I have a gradle script with a test task using Jacoco for reports. The build.gradle looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
apply plugin: "sonar-runner"

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testHandleProfiling true
        testFunctionalTest true
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            testCoverageEnabled true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    apply plugin: 'android-unit-test'

    dependencies {
        testCompile 'org.easytesting:fest:1.0.16'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.10'
        testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.4'
        testCompile 'com.squareup:fest-android:1.0.8'
    }
}

def coverageSourceDirs = [
        '../app/src/main/java', 'src/gen'
]

task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: "testDebug") {
    group = "Reporting"
    description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports after running tests."
    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = true
    }

    classDirectories = fileTree(
            dir: './build/intermediates/classes/debug',
            excludes: ['**/R.class',
                       '**/R$*.class'
            ])
    sourceDirectories = files(coverageSourceDirs)
    executionData = files('build/jacoco/testDebug.exec')
}

sonarRunner {

    sonarProperties {

        property "sonar.projectKey", "coverage-example"
        property "sonar.projectName", "Coverage Example"
        property "sonar.projectVersion", "1.0"

        property "sonar.sources", "src/main/java"
        property "sonar.binaries", "build"
        property "sonar.test", "src/test/java"

        property "sonar.language", "java"
        property "sonar.profile", "Android Lint"
        property "sonar.android.lint.report", "lint-report.xml"
        property "sonar.dynamicAnalysis", "reuseReports"
        property "sonar.sourceEncoding", "UTF-8"

        property "sonar.junit.reportsPath", "build/outputs/reports/coverage/debug"
        property "sonar.cobertura.reportPath", "build/outputs/reports/coverage/debug/cobertura.xml"
        property "sonar.java.coveragePlugin", "cobertura"

        property "sonar.host.url", "https://sonar.domain.com"

        property "sonar.jdbc.url", "jdbc:mysql://sonar.domain.com:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance"

        property "sonar.jdbc.username", "someuser"
        property "sonar.jdbc.password", "somepass"
    }

}
```

Running on the local machine all tests runs and I get the reports as expected. But running on the bamboo server I can see in the log that the task is skipped:

```
build   05-May-2015 16:19:24    :app:validateDebugSigning
build   05-May-2015 16:19:25    :app:packageDebug
build   05-May-2015 16:19:25    :app:zipalignDebug
build   05-May-2015 16:19:25    :app:assembleDebug
build   05-May-2015 16:19:25    :app:compileTestDebugJava
build   05-May-2015 16:19:25    :app:processTestDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
build   05-May-2015 16:19:25    :app:testDebugClasses
build   05-May-2015 16:19:25    :app:testDebug
build   05-May-2015 16:19:25    :app:jacocoTestReport SKIPPED
build   05-May-2015 16:19:26    :app:sonarRunner
build   05-May-2015 16:19:26    SonarQube Runner 2.3
build   05-May-2015 16:19:26    Java 1.7.0_79 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
build   05-May-2015 16:19:26    Linux 3.13.0-46-generic amd64
build   05-May-2015 16:19:26    INFO: Runner configuration file: NONE
build   05-May-2015 16:19:26    INFO: Project configuration file: /bamboo/xml-data/build-dir/TSTIOSAPPA-TP-BDA/app/build/tmp/sonarRunner/sonar-project.properties
build   05-May-2015 16:19:26    INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
build   05-May-2015 16:19:26    INFO: Work directory: /bamboo/xml-data/build-dir/TSTIOSAPPA-TP-BDA/app/build/sonar
build   05-May-2015 16:19:26    INFO: SonarQube Server 5.1
```

Since I don't get any errors I don't understand what the problem is. Gradle is executed with the gradle-wrapper, so it's building with the same version on both machines. Any ideas?

EDIT:

I've looked at [Running jacocoReport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20032366/running-jacocoreport), but that doesn't really explain why **it's working on my local machine and not on the build server**. And if I add test task (with java plugin) I get the following error:

```
The 'java' plugin has been applied, but it is not compatible with the Android plugins.
```

And if I don't apply java plugin I get the following error:

```
Could not find method test() for arguments [build_58yd8leqt3uhm31fecj9zk2qm$_run_closure4@3a73cd3f] on project ':app'.
```

But maybe I'm totally misunderstanding how to use the test task? Could not find method test() for arguments [build_58yd8leqt3uhm31fecj9zk2qm$_run_closure4@3a73cd3f] on project ':app'.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running jacocoReport](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20032366/running-jacocoreport)

Comment: It will be skipped only if the input data what your jacocoTestReport task needs is missing i.e. on your local machine you may be generating the class files and .exec file successfully but on the bamboo server, you are not (especially the .exec file). To generate jacoco reports/coverage, you have to run the respective task (andriodTest) and if they need to run behind an external JVM (other than what Gradle uses) i.e. Tomcat JVM for running non-unit tests, then you have to first start Tomcat (jacocoagent.jar must be configured first to Tomcat JVM), then run your non-unit tests and stop Tomcat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jacocoTestReport task is skipped when there is no coverage data to process.

Coverage data is produced when running tests. On android, the task androidTest will execute the tests.

To generate jacoco report you must run the tests with a line like this :

```
.\gradlew androidTest
```