# Eclipse - Java - Gradle is skipping jacocoTestReport

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, jacoco

Project structure:

```
    src/main/java
    src/main/resources
    src/test/java
```

Gradle version : 2.2.1

Here is my build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: 'jacoco'
    version = '1.0'
   sourceCompatibility = 1.7
   targetCompatibility = 1.7

 test {
    include 'src/test/java'
    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport

   }

  jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.7.6.201602180812"

  }

 jacocoTestReport {
  group = "Reporting"
  description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports after running tests."
  additionalSourceDirs = files(sourceSets.main.allJava.srcDirs)
  reports {
      xml.enabled false
      csv.enabled false
      html.destination "${buildDir}/reports/jacoco/html"
}
}
```

when I run gradle task as "test jacocoTestReport", I am getting the below results

```
  :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
  :processResources UP-TO-DATE
  :classes UP-TO-DATE
  :compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
  :processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
  :testClasses UP-TO-DATE
  :test UP-TO-DATE
  :jacocoTestReport SKIPPED
```

can someone please suggest what should be added to execute jacoco test report.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to generate the code coverage results with the following set up.

```
 apply plugin: 'jacoco'
 jacocoTestReport {
   reports {
   xml.enabled false
   csv.enabled false
   html.destination "${buildDir}/jacocoHtml"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The task will only run if coverage data is available. You can make sure of that by also running the `test` task.

*Source - [Running jacocoReport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20032366/running-jacocoreport)*

Answer (score 2):

You can force it to run with:

> jacocoTestReport {
> onlyIf = {
> true
> }
> }

This will probably give an error (there's a reason it didnt run in the first place), but the error should give more information.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, none of these answers worked for me.
**For Spring 2.5 Users, who got stuck with it for hours** -*just like myself*.

I had a similar issue.
I was not having the ***exec*** file generated.

And because of that ,
I found that the jacocoTestReport was simply "**skipped**".

**I got it fixed by adding** :

```
test {
  useJUnitPlatform()
  finalizedBy jacocoTestReport // report is always generated after tests run
}
```

That's because I'm using **Junit5 with spring boot 2.X** - **Gradle 7.1**

And as of today Junit5 is not invoked by default in the test task.

Comment: Finally! 

adding `useJUnitPlatform()` is what worked for me. without this the tests weren't even running I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Late at party, but none of the answers above solved for me. Instead, changing

```
dependencies {
    testCompile 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.0.0-M2'
}
```

to

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.5.2'
}
```

worked like a charm ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58178616)).